# Google App Engine: Sorting collections in a many-to-many relationship

Tags: google-app-engine, many-to-many, google-cloud-datastore, modeling

consider the following model:

```
class Tweet(db.Model):
    text = db.StringProperty
    created_at = db.DateTimeProperty()

class Company(db.Model):
    short_name = db.StringProperty()
    full_name = db.StringProperty()
    oneword_name = db.StringProperty()

class TweetMentionsCompany(db.Model):
    tweet = db.ReferenceProperty(Tweet, required=True,
                        collection_name='mentions_companies')
    company = db.ReferenceProperty(Company, required=True, 
                        collection_name='tweets_mentioned_in')
```

If I have a value for Company.oneword_name, how can I get a list of the 100 most recent tweets the related company is mentioned in, in chronological order?

My current code looks something like the following, but I am not sure how to modify for chronological order:

```
company = models.Company().all().filter('oneword_name = ', oneword_name.lower()).get()

for e,tmc in enumerate(company.tweets_mentioned_in):
    if e>100: break
    print_tweet_lite(self, tmc.tweet)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add field `created_at = db.DateTimeProperty()` into your's `TweetMentionsCompany`, and sort by it.

It's NoSQL, "*database normalization*" isn't working well here

Comment: Thank you, I thing I'll go with this. It's shocking that something so simple is dependent on the relational model.

Comment: @Alexandros Is It? Your relational DB would require a join, imposing a significant performance impact for something that's simply solved by denormalization.

Answer (score 1):

That kind of 'join' based query isn't possible in the datastore. If I were you, what I would do is create a `[ListProperty][1]` on `Tweet` that contains a list of the companies mentioned - this list can be easily computed at the same time as you were planning to compute the `TweetMentionsCompany` entities.

You can then do `filter('company = ', company)` on `Tweet` to find the list of tweets that mention a company (this will match if any company in the list matches the given company) and sort it any way you want.

Comment: This is definitely a neater option, since there's going to be a limited number of mentions per tweet.

Comment: Yup. As long as your tweeps are talking about less than 5000 companies in their 140 characters, you're good to go :)